# Python PyQT gestures

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, gesture

I want to enable use of PyQT gestures in my application. Anybody has an example or some short code that could demonstrate use of gesture control in PyQT application?

I tried googling around but could find only one post about customizing the gesture... I am not that far yet at all, I just want to see how to bind the gesture and callback in Python QT app.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm working the same problem.  No reason why it shouldn't work, by simply translating some of the C++ examples, but its bleeding edge.

For example, won't work on Linux desktop (just Windows) without Qt 5 or a lot of work.  See http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12664.  If I get Qt 5 installed, I hope to post a Python example.

I am using PySide, and the QtGraphicsFramework and have a small test program.  Another more sophisticated test, of custom gestures, is crashing, not just throwing exceptions, and I'm suspecting the Python binding.

There are plenty of nuances.  If any platform is good for learning, it should be Qt and Python.  Go figure why there are no examples yet.